# Codeigniter - Delete a row from the codeigniter table class library which is generated in the controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and i have a table created displaying contacts, it is created using the codeigniter table library in the controller (which is the issue ill get to) and displayed to the view.. i want to be able to delete a single row

Controller

```
function getDisplayUsersTable()
{

    $this->load->model('Contacts_model');       
    $this->load->library('table');     
    $this->table->set_heading('Check', 'Contact ID','Fullname', 'Email', 'Country', 'Gender', 'User_ID', 'Delete');


    $style = array('table_open'  => '<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">');
    $this->table->set_template($style);



$contacts = $this->Contacts_model->getUsers($this->session->user_id);

  $tableData = '';
  foreach($contacts as $contact) {

    array_unshift($contact, '<input type="checkbox" label="check">');

    $this->table->add_row($contact);
  }     
    return $this->table->generate();

}
```

The Model

```
 function getUsers($user_id)
 {


return $this->db->get_where('contacts', array('users_id' => $user_id))-
>result_array();
 }
```

Then the View is simply:

```
   <div>
           <?php


           echo $contacttable;?>
       </div>
```

So this is where my issue lies, i currently have a different table generated from the database displaying Template Items.. and i was able to add a delete function to it as the table is designed like this on the view:

```
  <tbody>
<?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
<tr class="myrow" data-id="<?=$row->idtemplates;?>">

      <td>Template</td>
    <td><?php echo $row->idtemplates; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row->users_temp_id; ?></td>
      <td><button class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><a style="color:white;" href ="<?php echo site_url('Dashboard/delete/'.$row->idtemplates);?>">delete</a></button></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Controller

```
            function delete($idtemplate) {
$this->load->model("Template_model");
$this->Template_model->delete_row($idtemplate);
```

}

Model

```
public function delete_row($idtemplate){
    $this -> db -> where('idtemplates', $idtemplate);
    $this -> db -> delete('templates');
    redirect('dashboard');
}
```

So my question is really, how do i take this logic used on the Template table which is coded in the view and apply it to the codeigniter table class library, which is designed in the controller.. i apologise for the length of this and appreciate any help as i am very confused by it.. but im sure it is just a matter of placing the code in the correct place?

Comment: because i couldnt get it working otherwise

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? I'm having trouble following. Basically you want to add a delete link to your ci generated table?

Comment: @Alex yes exactly, i want to add a delete column to the ci generated table, but having trouble applying the same logic that ive used on the template table, as the ci generated table has no code in the view

Comment: Ok I know what you want then but the table library kindof sucks and doesn't really have that functionality. Your best bet is making the table manually with a foreach.

Comment: @alex nah i think there will be a way to manually add it into the table library

Comment: If you look at the docs you'll see the table library is relatively rudimentary and doesn't support callbacks: You need to pass a few variables from your db row to the individual rows delete row column. Again, no support for this - read the docs if you don't believe me.

Comment: But outside the library you might be able to just use array push to add delete like you did with the checkbox. Just do it after the array unshift.